# ARM Template - complex calculation

Tags: azure-resource-manager

numOfVolumes = round(-1.1966 + (27.0/400.0)*(((400*400) - ((400 - (vsnapSizeInGB/1024))**2))**0.5))

```
      "copy": [
        {
          "name": "dataDisks",
          "count":<formula to calculate amount of disks>,
          "input": {
            "diskSizeGB":<formula to calculate each disk size - besides maybe a leftover disk>,
            "lun": "[copyIndex('dataDisks')]",
            "createOption": "Empty"
          }
        }
      ]
```

2. I have the following password requirement to be validated in arm template, using regex looks difficult, is there a way I can a powershell command to validate the value of the parameter and then return true / false based on that the arm template throws an error.
      The minimum acceptable password length is 15 characters.
There must be eight characters in the new password that are not present in the previous password(provided).
The new password must contain at least one character from each of the classes (numbers, uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and other).
The maximum number of identical consecutive characters that are allowed in the new password is three characters.
The maximum number of identical consecutive class of characters that are allowed in the new password is four characters.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What is the question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use PowerShell to perform the calculation for `numOfVolumes` and then pass in the value as a parameter. If you must perform the calculation in an ARM template then I suggest you have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-numeric
You're probably not going to enjoy writing the formula with: add, copyIndex, div, float, int, max, min, mod, mul, and sub.

As for the question about a password generator, Google provides some good links, such as http://www.theservergeeks.com/how-to-powershell-password-generator/ Again, PowerShell will be the best bet on generating the type of password that meets your requirements.